# QNetworkAccessManager: how to make sure download is finished?

Tags: qt

If I do:

```
QNetworkRequest newRequest(url);
newRequest.setUrl(url);
QNetworkReply *reply = networkManager->get(newRequest);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onRetrievedDownLoadInfo()));
```

and

```
void myClass::onRetrievedDownLoadInfo()
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(QObject::sender());

    if (!reply)
    {
        ui->upgradeLog->appendPlainText("Download failed, invalid context");
        return;
    }

    //Remeber to delete the reply
    //---------------------------
    reply->deleteLater();

    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        ui->upgradeLog->appendPlainText("Download failed, invalid context");
        return;
    }

    reply->readAll();
    ...
}
```

Can I say that when the program reaches line

> reply->readAll();

All the content replied by the server is successfully received?

Is it possible the `reply->readAll();` only returns part of the reply due to network failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onRetrievedDownLoadInfo()));
```

you are not doing it in the correct way. Use a `QNetworkAccessManager` to check the network is working:

```
QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;
req.setConfiguration(manager.defaultConfiguration());

connect(&req, SIGNAL(networkAccessibleChanged(QNetworkAccessManager::NetworkAccessibility)), this, SLOT(networkAccessibleChanged(QNetworkAccessManager::NetworkAccessibility)));
```

Comment: Can you state more clearly what is the error? I didn't get it.

Comment: You are trying to slot `onRetrievedDownLoadInfo()`, **but** you won't slot in there when there will be internet problems, that's the root of the downloading problem. The correct way of doing it is to use a QNetworkAccessManager. See [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-downloadmanager-example.html).